# Jenkins Checkout on Push to nexus

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, nexus

I am working on a project that will run SonarQube only on builds pushed to Nexus, this would be taking the place of GIT.

The flow I envisioned would be, new code is pushed to Nexus, Jenkins wakes up through Polling or Webhook and runs SonarQube against the last code committed

Any recommendation on tools or guidance are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What did you try to setup this pipeline?

Comment: hi @JeroenHeier, sorry not sure i understand what you mean.